# How to change the text color according to the theme of the app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, bloc

I'm currently exploring flutter. here, I'm making a news app using news API. I'm using bloc not stateful widgets. I have three screens for news categories. The problem in the dark theme, I made a button to switch between themes, but the text used for the titles for each item in the list doesn't switch accordingly. **however**, If I switch between screens changing states the color of the text is set right - black in the light mode and white in the dark one -

[link for the project I'm learning from](https://github.com/abdullahmansss/udemy/tree/full_news_app/lib)

**Main**

```
themeMode: AppCubit.get(context).isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
```

**DARK THEME**

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
                    bodyText1: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
```

the light theme has a black color instead.
**FUNCTION TO CHANGE THE MODE**

```
bool isDark = false;
  void changeMode () {
  isDark = !isDark;
  print(isDark.toString());
  emit(NewsThemeModeChanged());
}
```

**DARK MODE BUTTON**

```
IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AppCubit.get(context).changeMode();
                    },
                    icon: Icon (Icons.brightness_2),
                ),
```

**EACH NEWS ITEM BUILDER**

```
Widget buildNewsItem (dynamic article, BuildContext context) => Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 120.0,
        height: 120.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
              '${article['urlToImage']}',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10.0,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 120.0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  '${article['title']}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '${article['author']}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

**FIRST SCREEN**

```
class BusinessScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer <NewsCubit, NewsStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state)
      {
        var list = NewsCubit.get(context).business;
        return ConditionalBuilder(
            condition: list.isNotEmpty,
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
              body: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildNewsItem(list[index], context),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => buildListSeparator(),
                  itemCount: 15,
              ),
            ),
            fallback: (context)=>Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the theme cubit state extend `Equatable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these methods

1. change the BlocConsumer context

```dart
BlocConsumer <NewsCubit, NewsStates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (conContext, state)
```

pass this context to buildsNewItem,

```dart
buildNewsItem(list[index], conontext),
```

2. change this ConditionalBuilder context

```dart
ConditionalBuilder(builder:(_){})
```

Comment: This worked just fine, thank you. Could you please give some advice to better understand what was the problem and why changing context solved it for me while in the original project I learn from it worked without this change

Comment: start from 10.50 to as u want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laqnY0NjU3M&list=PLptHs0ZDJKt_T-oNj_6Q98v-tBnVf-S_o&index=7